# absolutely NO functions surrounding a tstamp in a SQL? Hourly historical data query

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, timestamp

I need to obtain for some specific hours data for a specific week day back to 10 weeks.  The DB I work on is Oracle. I came up with the following condtions with the time stamp field:

```
TO_CHAR(hy.tstamp,'HH24')='10' 
AND hy.tstamp > sysdate - 70  
AND mod(extract ( day from sysdate-1) - extract ( day from hy.tstamp), 7) =0
```

Someone told me "absolutely NO functions surrounding a tstamp" (for performance reasons?). How would you to specify the conditions without operations on the time stamp field?

Comment: who is someone?  You can't let people blather on without holding them accountable to explain their reasoning.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You are asking how to get and deal with Timestamp data without getting/dealing with Timestamp data?

Comment: please provide us a sqlfiddle, i think i know the issue you are seeing.

Comment: To WootMoo: The person I work with is a very senior member with DB expertise. I'm more an application developer. He said 'no no no' to the the query I came with (I'm only doing prototyping and analysis now).  He is very self-possessed -- not sure if he'll accept the solution you provided at all. To David Stakey: yes, I wanted the solution as you stated.

Comment: Ah, the best kind.  Interesting that he did not suggest function based indexes.  Try that out and give us a fiddle, this will help us help you.

Comment: Wow, he sounds like a bad person to work with. "you must abide by my absolute rule, and don't expect me to help you"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the time slices without functions or function indexes if you join to a table of acceptable ranges. You can create one on the fly like this (note that you need the functions to create the table, but you won't need them afterward):

```
SELECT
  TRUNC(SYSDATE + 6) - (7 * LEVEL) + INTERVAL '10' HOUR AS StartAt,
  TRUNC(SYSDATE + 6) - (7 * LEVEL) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR AS EndAt
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

With today's date being 5/8/2013, this will give you the following:

```
STARTAT             ENDAT
------------------- -------------------
05/07/2013 10:00:00 05/07/2013 11:00:00
04/30/2013 10:00:00 04/30/2013 11:00:00
04/23/2013 10:00:00 04/23/2013 11:00:00
04/16/2013 10:00:00 04/16/2013 11:00:00
04/09/2013 10:00:00 04/09/2013 11:00:00
04/02/2013 10:00:00 04/02/2013 11:00:00
03/26/2013 10:00:00 03/26/2013 11:00:00
03/19/2013 10:00:00 03/19/2013 11:00:00
03/12/2013 10:00:00 03/12/2013 11:00:00
03/05/2013 10:00:00 03/05/2013 11:00:00
```

Now just join it to your query to get the time slices you want, and note that you don't need functions:

```
WITH TimeRanges AS (
  SELECT
    TRUNC(SYSDATE + 6) - (7 * LEVEL) + INTERVAL '10' HOUR AS StartAt,
    TRUNC(SYSDATE + 6) - (7 * LEVEL) + INTERVAL '11' HOUR AS EndAt
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
)
SELECT
  ... whatever ...
FROM your_table hy
INNER JOIN TimeRanges ON
  hy.tstamp >= TimeRanges.StartAt AND
  hy.tstamp < TimeRanges.EndAt
```

If your DB person understands that filtering on timestamp functions kills performance (unless, as Woot4Moo points out, they implement function indexes), they'll understand that the functions used to create the table of timeslices won't impact the larger query.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the person complaining about performance has never heard of function based indexes.

```
Create index char_hy_stamp on my_table(to_char(hy.tstamp,'HH24'));
```

This should avoid the full table scan that is undoubtedly part of your explain plan.  As soon as you get your sqlfiddle functioning we can go from there.